# Modify HTML from PhP

Tags: c#, php

I have a question. In ASP technology, developers can modify the front-end writing instructions in the code-behind:

Default.aspx:

```
<div id="modify" runat="server"></div>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
modify.InnerHtml = "blablablablabla";
```

It is possible to do something similar in HTML and PhP? How is the way? I don´t want to use jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: But you should use jQuery ^^ If you want to you can use DOMDocument (http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you asking how to insert text in PHP?

```
<div id="modify" runat="server"><?php print 'text'; ?></div>
```

You do it by print/echo. You can print strings, or variables. You cannot print when html was already sent to the browser. Only javascript then.
But you can always use ob_start to catch all text, and after generated html, get it to variable, to replace with what you wan't.

If you asking, how to work with existing page, use DomDocument or i will sugest SimpleHTMLDom library